# cant seem to style <td>?

Tags: html, html-table

Simple CSS:

```
table.tgi
{
    width:100%;
}

table.tgi td.labelcell
{
    text-align:right;
    color:Red;
}

table.tgi td.valuecell
{
    text-align:left;
    color:Green;
}
```

Simple HTML:

```
<table id="tgi" runat="server" width="100%">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="labelcell">ID:</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="labelcell">Originator:
                </td>
                <td class="valuecell"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="labelcell">Expected Ship Date:</td>
                <td class="valuecell"><asp:TextBox ID="txtExpectedShipDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td class="labelcell">Actual Ship Date:</td>
                <td class="valuecell"><asp:TextBox ID="txtActualShipDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

But the TD styling does not work...

## Edit

I tried this:

```
table#tgi
{
    width:100%;
}

table#tgi td.labelcell
{
    text-align:right;
    color:Red;
}

table#tgi td.valuecell
{
    text-align:left;
    color:Green;
}
```

With HTML:

```
 <table id="tgi" runat="server">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="labelcell">ID:</td>
                <td class="valuecell"></td>
                <td class="labelcell">Originator:</td>
                <td class="valuecell"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="labelcell">Expected Ship Date:</td>
                <td class="valuecell"><asp:TextBox ID="txtExpectedShipDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td class="labelcell">Actual Ship Date:</td>
                <td class="valuecell"><asp:TextBox ID="txtActualShipDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

This doesnt work...
but if I change it to a class it works...but I want to try it with an ID???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table has an ID if tgi, not a class.

Fix #1

```
<table class="tgi" runat="server" width="100%">
```

Fix #2

```
table#tgi
{
    width:100%;
}

table#tgi td.labelcell
{
    text-align:right;
    color:Red;
}

table#tgi td.valuecell
{
    text-align:left;
    color:Green;
}
```

Comment: Could I change the table to use an ID instead of the class in the CSS?  table#tgi
{
 width:100%;
}

Comment: -very strange when I use .tgi as a class it works.  But when i use it as an ID the page displays as if it doesnt see the CSS.  I put in table#tgi{ width:100%;} and my html is <table id="tgi">....

Answer (score 0):

Since tgi is a class on the table tag your selector has to be table#tgi. See the [css standard for more info on selectors.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

You're selectors state:

```
table.tgi
```

This means a `table` with the class `tgi`.

Your table doesn't have this class, but it has the value as an ID. To select as an ID you need to use `#` instead of `.`

```
table#tgi
```

[**-- SEE EXAMPLE --**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/wUq4H/)